# Direction of EMF and Induced current through the circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

When the circuit shown above is moved with a constant velocity to the left I know that B is going to have the higher potential.

And I believe that the current flows clockwise that is in the sense of AEDCB.

But my tutor says that the current flows in the sense ABCDE,saying that it is similar to having a battery across BD with the positive terminal at B instead of the half loop BCD with the magnetic field..

I am very confused with this matter.
Am I correct or is my tutor correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbf{v}$ is to the left and $\mathbf{B}$ is into the page, $\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}$ is towards the bottom of the page.

Thus, a mobile *positive* charge would flow *clockwise* (AEDCB) around the circuit and so the *electric* current is clockwise ('up' through the resistor). Recall that the [direction of electric current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current#Conventions) is in the direction of positive charge flow.

However, your tutor may be referring to *electron* current which is in the opposite direction of electric current (electrons are negatively charged). The electron current is thus counter-clockwise (ABCDE).

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the answer one you can replace BCD with BC to easily understand ,let for understanding the direction we will apply lenz law that is current induced in a coil in such fashion that it will oppose the cause ,as flux in the coil is decreasing as it is move toward left so current will be in clockwise direction to oppose decrease in current it mean your TUTOR IS RIGHT now coming to your question that B should be at higher potential yiu can simply understand it by lorentz force equation F=QVB there is cross product between V and B that is when your teacher talk about battery yiu can simply derive polarity use right hand palm rule put right hand finger in direction of flux your thumb will indicate velocity and and point that faces palm will be at higher potential YOUR TEACHER IS is simply talking about electron because in this equation q replace by e which is counter or anti clockwise